# Bitcoin Block Download frozen

Tags: blockchain

For 5 days now my block download has been frozen at 57%. I tried downloading a new wallet to a different computer (which did download all the way), but I can't figure out how to pull the information from my frozen wallet to this one so I can recieve my bitcoins. Or how to get the blocks to finish downloading on my original wallet. Any help would be much appreciated, I need my money asap!

Comment: I've tried uninstalling the wallet as well, but the block download is still frozen at 57%!

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with the version of the bitcoin wallet that you are running. Are you running the latest version 0.6.3?
Second, which OS are you using, It'll help us to tell you which files to delete in order to restart the chain download.

Delete the blockchain data and reload the chain.  !!! Do not delete the files wallet.dat, addr.dat and bitcoin.conf. Except for those, stop the wallet, delete all other files, restart the wallet.

The files you'll see and that you can delete are, e.g. blk0001.dat, blk0002.dat, blkindex.dat, *.log, peers.dat, the whole subdirectory 'database'

Comment: Yes I know I have the latest version, and Windows 7. I could not figure out what to delete to restart the download, that would be much simpler. But how do I delete the blockchain data to reload it?

Comment: You should have a directory called something like this: c:\users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin.  This directory contains all the data. Best is to make a backup of the whole folder then proceed deleting all files in that folder except for the ones described in the answer. I.e. Stop the wallet, delete the files, start the wallet.

Comment: I've looked through all of the files on my computer related to the wallet and don't see any like that. I can use a computer but I'm not extremely savvy, what do you mean by subdirectory database?

Comment: Did you find the folder called "AppData"? If not then it is probably due to the fact that this is a system folder and per default system folders are not shown in the Explorer. You will need to activate the Explorer options to show system folder.  You should be able to do this via the command prompt.
c:
cd \users
cd <username>     Replace with your login user name
cd appdata\roaming\bitcoin
The folder bitoin then contains a subfolder called database.

Comment: I cannot find that directory/folder

Comment: I search "AppData" with no results, but I do not know how to "activate the Explorer options" in order to show the system folder.

Comment: Open the explorer, then press the ALT button, a menu should appear at the top of the Explorer window. Select Tools->Folder Options->View  and then select the option "Show hidden files, folder and drives".

Comment: Ok I selected that, and searched AppData, but still cannot find it

Comment: I have a wallet on another computer I was able to download completely. Is there anyway to transfer the info from my frozen wallet to this one so I can collect my money?

Comment: You will need to locate that directory first, no matter what you do, because it contains your wallet.dat file.  Send me an email to the address in my profile, that'll make communcation easier.

Comment: Send me an email to aeckert1@gmail.com  That'll be more effective in resolving this.

Comment: What was the solution?  It might help others having the same trouble who find themselves reading this.

Comment: Solution: delete the blockchain files and download the chain again.